# How to print all values of an object methods?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the output list of `dir(requests)` and I want to print all of the values.

Something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
for i in dir(request):
    print(i)
    print(request.i)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, please advise what I am missing?

Comment: @PythonLover: What? No, that won't work at all. It'll just be broken in a different way.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am trying to get a value from request I send using httr package in R to my Python backend. I keep getting none when I print the request.

Please advise.

Comment: Well one thing is that you are doing `dir(request)` instead of `dir(requests)`

Comment: @RoadRunner because I do this in my Python code:
```from flask import Flask, request```

Comment: @SteveS You should include that in your question. It was ambiguous if you were calling the `requests` module or something else.

Comment: I havnt downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is a string here, you can't directly access methods like this, the `getattr` function is what has to be used:

```py
for i in dir(request):
    print(i)
    print(getattr(request, i))
```